# Django 4 By Example code doesn't show body-contents at all

Tags: web, python-3.10, django-4.1

I'm reading a book the title is Django 4 By Example.

I tried to make chapter01 & 02.

I wrote codes following the explanation of the book, everything is okay without bugs, but the result was not good.
In my case, the body is empty.

So I download & migrate the canonical codes and execute it, but the result was the same.
Naturally I made some articles by admin as a superuser.
This result is like this.

[image]

I'm new to django, and to make web application, but this code is  undoubtly the same as example codes.I'm using `windows11` so I tried to do the same thing on `windows10`, but the result was the same.I tried to do on the Microsoft Edge & Google Chrome.

code is here. This image is chapter02.

[django 4 by example github](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-4-by-example)

Do you know this is what kind of problems?
Is this occured to me only?I don't find out the person who run into the same problem.

Many readers say this book is wonderful, yes, I think so, too. But I'm embarassed at this result.

This is the command prompt message.

[image]

Comment: If you're just starting the server - is there any data in the database?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Does it mean that my article? The title is "who is this man?" or "what is it?".  Or in models.py?Sorry, I have no enough knowledge.